# ChartJS: Show all tooltips with Total for Multi Pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a Pie chart with multiple rings and created a Custom Tooltips function with below code:

```
function tooltipWithTotalP(tooltipItem, data) { 
var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
var values = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
var total = 0;
for (var i in values) {
    total += values[i];
}
var percentage = Math.round((value / total) * 100);
var totally = total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex !== data.datasets.length - 1) {
    return label + " : " + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' (' + percentage + '%)';
} else {
    return [label + " : " + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' (' + percentage + '%)', "Total : " + totally];
}
}
```

The above function is expected to show all the Label values with Total at bottom from the PieChart, but it is showing only individual Values from First Dataset and individual values + Total from second Dataset.

Individual lebels are showing as Undefined.

Here is the JSfille https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x03w2qbk/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see every label remove the tooltipItem.index

```
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].labels;
```

To list all the labels in the tool tip is straight forward.

```
var label = [];
    for (var j in labels) {
        var percentage = Math.round((values[j] / total) * 100);
        label.push (labels[j] + " : " + values[j].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' (' + percentage + '%)');
    }       
    label.push("Total : " + totally)
    return label;
```

Label color is derived from the datasetIndex so the label background colour doesn't propagate, you will have to create a custom tooltip or disable `displayColors`.

```
custom: function(tooltip) {
    tooltip.displayColors = false;
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drillep/xb4g19en/2/

Comment: No, It will show individual Label in each row (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/Lwqn5e80/12/)

Comment: However, in the tooltip it should list all the Labels as List. See this Bar Chart (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/r23y0h6n/). Tried the same for Pie Chart, but not working.

Comment: Do you need colours? :)

Comment: Yes, the Label background colors.

Answer (score 0):

The label variable in the label function needs an array index.

```
var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].labels[tooltipItem.index];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drillep/40htzrdn/

Comment: I want to show all the labels in the ToolTip with Total; like "Mumbai, Chennai, Hyderabad, Bangalore, Total" for the first ring and "Arrivals,Departure, Total" for the second ring.

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to display every label for the dataset in the tooltip plus the total.  The tooltip that pops up above each segment as you roll over?  Or do you mean in the labels below the doughnut chart?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all the Labels from each segment with Total at last in the Tooltip.